# Prove the continuity of $f-g$ and $|f|$ when $f$, $g$ are continuous.

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, proof-writing

The original exercise is as follows:

Consider two real functions $f$ and $g$, both are continuous in $a \in \mathbb R$.

Hence

(i) f + g, f-g and $f\times g$ is continuous in a;

(ii) if g(a) $\neq$ 0, then $\frac{f}g$ is continuous in a;

(iii) |f| is continuous in a;

> Proof the statements f-g and |f| only (because I've already done the proof for $f+g$, $f\times$ and $f/g$ with the $\epsilon$-$\delta$-definition.

To simplify the case $f-g$, I'll show you my proof of f+g.

$\underline{f + g:}$
$(\forall \epsilon \gt 0)(\exists \delta_1 , \delta_2\gt 0)(\forall x \in \mathbb R)$

$(|x-a|\lt \delta_1 \Rightarrow |f(x) -f(a)|\lt \frac {\epsilon}{2})$

$(|x-a|\lt \delta_2 \Rightarrow |g(x) -g(a)|\lt \frac {\epsilon}{2})$

Let $\delta := min\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$

Then we have for $|x-a|\lt \delta$

$|(f+g)(x) - (f+g)(a)| \le |f(x)-f(a)| + |g(x) -g(a)| \le \frac {\epsilon}{2} + \frac {\epsilon}{2}= \epsilon$

$\underline{f-g:}$

Analogously to the inequality $|a+b| \le |a| + |b|$

I only need to change the definition of f and the $g$-side in the last in- and equality of the previous statement of $f+g$.

So $(|x-a|\lt \delta_2 \Rightarrow |f(x) -f(a)|\lt \frac {3\cdot\epsilon}{2})$ 
$|(f+g)(x) - (f+g)(a)| \le |f(x)-f(a)| + |g(x) -g(a)| \le \frac {3\cdot\epsilon}{2} - \frac {\epsilon}{2}= \epsilon$

And about |f| do you really need to show that like the previous ones? Can't you say it literally follows out of the $\epsilon$-$\delta$-definition?

Comment: for $f-g$, prove first that if $g$ is continuous then so is $-g$ and then use the the fact that $f+(-g)$ is continuous. and for $|f|$ yes it is an (easy) $\epsilon-\delta$-proof.

Comment: And the way I did it for $f-g$, can you make it a valid proof by correcting some statements. @yanko

Comment: you have $|(f-g)(x)-(f-g)(a)|\leq|f(x)-f(a)|+|g(a)-g(x)|$, and it is obvious that $|g(a)-g(x)|=|g(x)-g(a)|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|(f-g)(x) - (f-g)(a)| = |f(x)-f(a)+g(a)-g(x)| \le |f(x)-f(a)| + |g(a) -g(x)| = |f(x)-f(a)|+|g(x)-g(a)|$

For the second part, utilize $\big||x|-|y|\big| \leq |x-y|$.

Answer (score 0):

It's much quicker to just prove it generally with the Definition that: $\lim _{x_1 \to x} f(x_1)= f(x)$ What you are doing is way Overkill for nothing.

1. If you have shown that the Addition of a continous function is again continuous, you automatically get the subtraction as well.

Comment: Well it was a task in the first chapter of calculus. We're not at the paragraph of limits yet.