# Proof $f-g$ and $|f|$ is continuous with the $\epsilon$-$\delta$-definition

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, epsilon-delta

The task is to prove that $f-g$ and $|f|$ are continuous in a given that two real functions $f$ and $g$ are both continuous in $a \in \mathbb R$.

Proof of $f-g$:

First of all one has to prove that $g$ is continuous and that implies that $-g$ is continuous. After that one needs to use the proof of the sum of two functions $f$ and $g$ so that $f+(-g)$. I've already written that proof in here [1]

So I don't know how to prove that g is continuous unless it is directly from the $\epsilon$-$\delta$-definition but that I know wouldn't be sufficient.

Proof of $|f|$:

For this proof one needs to use the triangle inequality.

$(\forall \epsilon \gt 0)(\exists \delta\gt 0)(\forall x \in \mathbb R)(|x-a|\lt \delta \Longrightarrow ||f(x) -f(a)||\lt \epsilon$

$\Longrightarrow  ||f(x)- f(a)|| \le ||f(x)| -|f(a)|| \lt \epsilon$

This is the best I've got. Can you please help me proving the last two statements.

[1] : ([Prove the continuity of $f-g$ and $|f|$ when $f$, $g$ are continuous.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2454407/prove-the-continuity-of-f-g-and-f-when-f-g-are-continuous))

Comment: You are assuming $g$ is continuous, there is no need to prove it.

Comment: Huh, but this is a theorem in my calculus textbook . And the task is to prove that for $f+ g$, $f-g$, $f\cdot g$, $f \cdot \frac 1g$ and $|f|$ they're continuous in $a $

Comment: In your proof of $f-g$ you say that you have to prove $g$ is continuous, but this stipulation is stated in the problem itself, “...two real functions $f$ and $g$ both continuous...”

Comment: but you need to prove that operation between those two functions still remains continuous in $a \in \mathbb R$

Comment: Is something unclear? It has been 2 hours before I posted the question.

Comment: Ok, I understand now but I just got distracted by the fact that I needed to prove all of the statements (f+g;f-g;f*g;f*1/g;|f|) including this one. And how about the other one?

Comment: I've the proof of f - g which I thought too long about because I thought it should have a separate proof than of $f+g$

Comment: @Jason: Is my proof of |f| right?